# Advanced user registration library for ASP.NET?

Tags: library, c#, user-management, asp.net

I am developing a site for employers. Basically, the employers (aka the admins) need to be able to create limited user accounts for their employees. The employer needs to be able to manage their employees' membership information, including the ability to "Fire" (i.e. ban/delete accounts), hire (i.e. create new accounts), and set employee account permissions. Depending on the account permissions that the employer sets, the employee will have various levels of access to the web application's features.

I could develop a custom membership and role provider in ASP.NET MV4 to do this, but I am wondering if something like this has already been done. Basically, I am looking for an "admin system" library where admins can create and delete member accounts. Does such a library already exist, preferably with a commercially-usable license?

Comment: @arao6 you did indeed – but you forgot about the cost. Any budget, or must it come for free?